# I can't select an element that if selected randomly from a list, something else happens

Tags: python, list

How do I manage to get the system to print `This letter is "a".` when `a` in list `aList` is randomly selected?
This is what I have thought of and found, but it hasn't been working, and I have only been coding as of yesterday so my knowledge of it is limited.

```
import random
aList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
bList = random.choice(aList)
print(bList)
while True:
if aList.state == 0:
print("This letter is "a".")
```

Comment: what is the intent of `aList.state`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print when the letter is "a" create a if statement to do it:

> ```
> import random
> aList = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
> bList = random.choice(aList)
>
> if bList == "a":
>   print("the letter is a")
> else:
>   print(bList)
> ```

note: your code has a problem in the indexing of the while loop and if statement:

#before

> ```
> while True:
> if aList.state == 0:
> print("This letter is "a".")
> ```

#after

```
> while True:
>     if aList.state == 0:
>         print("This letter is a")
```